# How can I get the set the cursor to text in a combo-box xaml/c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, textbox

I've got a combo-box control and what I would like to do is, when a user selects the combo-box, the drop-down options are shown as is the text in the field. If I select the middle of "StackOverflow", at the moment, it highlights the full text and doesnt allow me to set the cursor in a particular position in the text. I'm wondering if this is possible and how can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to check how you need to set up `IsEditable` and `IsReadOnly` propertires for your ComboBox: [IsEditable and IsReadOnly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)

I suppose for your case it should be: `IsReadOnly = false` and `IsEditable = true`

Comment: I do have the IsEditable property set to true but am still unable to set cursor to part of the text. The full text field gets highlighted and clicking again displays the drop-down options.

Comment: @user3192935 I suppose you have more stuff in your code then. Provide your exact xaml and code-behind, if there is any.